# Time travel where you travel back in time in your own body?

Tags: time-travel, science-fiction-genre

I have a question. I read somewhere, but can't remember now.

What is the name of the time travel scenario used in science fiction where you travel back in time in your own body?

Comment: The name for this sort of time travel could vary broadly from work to work. If you are looking for a real-life definition, I would recommend [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! You might find [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel) or [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel_in_fiction) useful. If your question gets closed (I suspect it may), please don't be discouraged and do stick around here :-) You might also like to take our [tour] and check out [what sort of questions are on-topic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The question is not about a specific work of science fiction. It is about the genre. Isn't that what the science-fiction-genre tag is ***for***?

Comment: The answer is that there is no generally accepted name for that type of time travel. Richard Horton calls it [Time Travel Via One's Own Thread of Consciousness](http://www.sff.net/people/richard.Horton/timecon.htm) and describes it this way: "This list includes stories about people who travel through time along their own thread of consciousness. Typically, this means their future self 'possesses', if you will, their past self and relives a scene. One may or may not have the ability to act independently: typically not."

Comment: @user14111 - The question is either (a) about what this is called in the real world (which is as on-topic as asking what the definition of FTL travel is, i.e. not, and should be closed as off-topic, as @Rand’alThor did), or (b) what a general term for this sort of thing in fiction is (which should be closed as too broad, since there is no such term).

Comment: @user14111 On second thoughts, perhaps I closed this too quickly and it's not as clear-cut a case as I thought it was. My apologies. I've reopened it so that the community can decide whether or not it's really off-topic. (Fortunately nobody's votes to close were cancelled, since nobody had VTCed already before I did. So it's now in exactly the same state, as far as close/reopen votes go, as it was originally.)

Comment: @Adamant I edited it to make it more clearly about science fiction rather than the real world.

Comment: Besides the innumerable [tag:story-identification] questions erroneously tagged as [tag:science-fiction-genre] merely because they are science fiction, the tag is generally used for questions about genre development (such as [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126221/what-is-the-earliest-story-to-present-man-made-machines-as-a-threat-to-humans)). It could also be used for questions about the structure and conventions of the genre as a whole.

Comment: How on earth is this "too-broad"? If anything it belongs on ELL, but definitely not too-broad!

Comment: @Mooz - Because there is no commonly accepted term, and each author will tend to make up their own. It’s off-topic or too broad, depending. It’s like asking how cloning works in science fiction: the answer is “however you want it to.” There must be a hundred different terms for this in a hundred different works, with no etymological connection, consistency of usage, or indeed common meaning.

Comment: @Adamant "What is the name for this kind of time travel" belongs on scifi.SE just as surely as "what is the name for this kind of function" belongs on math.SE; nobody would refer the latter question to an English language site. Anyway, we surely have enough serious constructive questions about "how do they dispose of used condoms in Star Trek" and "does Harry wear boxers of briefs", that we may be permitted the occasional fun question like this one. BTW, "there is no commonly accepted term" is an ANSWER, probably correct, but I'd -1 it for lack of evidence.

Comment: @user14111 - If there were anything approaching a consistent name or names, I would tend to agree with you. I would not be voting to close “What is the the term for a separate space through which FTL craft travel?” But the problem is not that there is no answer. Rather, the *correct* answer is a list of innumerable individual terms, and thus simply too broad. If there were a consistent name, but it is not used in Sci-Fi, then I’d close as “not SFF” and send it to Physics or ELU. If there were a consistent name used broadly in SFF, I’d leave it open. No consistency whatsoever? Too broad.

Comment: Put another way, I certainly hope we would not be having this discussion for “What do we call a magic system that allows summoning demons?”

Comment: What’s more, of course, the poster appears to be trying to remember a specific term from a book that they read (“I read somewhere, but can’t remember now”), which they are *assuming* is in common usage.

Comment: I feel that even if the answer to this is a "list" type answer, it would still be a limited and finite list. Which is good.

Comment: @Randal'Thor " So it's now in exactly the same state, as far as close/reopen votes go, as it was originally." Except that I voted to reopen before you did. If I understand how these things work, that means I won't be able to vote to reopen after it's closed again.

Comment: @Adamant So according to you, we have to know the **answer** to the question, in order to know if it's on topic or not? If there is no such term, then **that is the answer**. But I'd like to see that posted as an actual **answer**, with evidence and citations, rather than rely on a comment from an anonymous user (not even on the "top users" list for the time-travel tag) telling me "if there was such a term I would have heard of it."

Comment: [Peggy Sue](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PeggySue)

Comment: Thank you all for  the info you provided me! The time travel I meant was like in Star Trek Generations when Picard comes back out in time out of the Nexus in his own body again.

Comment: @user14111 True; sorry about that.

Comment: So, something like [regression therapy](http://www.goodtherapy.org/learn-about-therapy/types/regression-therapy) but with your future memories/knowledge/point-of-view relocated to an earlier point in your life, along with the ability to *change* your actions in that earlier time?

Comment: TVTropes calls this [*Mental Time Travel.*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MentalTimeTravel)

Comment: Is there time-travel where you do it in *somebody else’s* body?? ([Oh wait, yes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Leap))

Comment: @HoomanGohari: "like in Star Trek Generations when Picard comes back out in time out of the Nexus in his own body again." - he probably doesn't; when he comes back, he enters elsewhere and much earlier than when he arrives at the launchpad for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

The term for a mind migrating from one body to another is metempsychosis. Mental time travel might be called transtemporal metempsychosis. However, since this form of metempsychosis involves time travel and the person replacing their own mind with their own mind, this term can be expanded to become chronautometempsychois. Literally, time-self-mindswap.

Most people will prefer to keep it simple. For example, psychic time-travel has been used to describe this and that's clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The *idea* of this type of personal life-regression time travel has been used [many, many times in all forms of media.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MentalTimeTravel) (tvtropes link). But as far as I can tell, there's no generally agreed-on *name* for it.